# Multimedia files .mp4, .mkv, .avi, .flac. Having a ( ? ) question mark

Tags: kubuntu

I use Kubuntu 17.10.1 (with the default DE KDE )

I've run a software application for cleaning, BleachBit, just to recover some space on my hard drive and after the cleaning process.

I found some of my files on Multimedia file icons has a ( ? ) question mark but it plays normally on my player.

[image: Question Marks on some Multimedia files .mp4, .avi, .mkv, .flac]

How can I restore or repair those ( ? ) question mark files.

Comment: You can set default Icons for those files but they don't need repaired.

Comment: One has to be careful with bleachbit! I would try Unity Tweak Tool as an absolutely last resort. Does bleachbit generate some sort of log of what it has deleted? There maybe some hints there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install Unity Tweak Tool with the Software Center....
Open Dash and type "Unity Tweak" and open that Program...

**DISCLAIMER**:
*On KDE Systems this may not be Possible, Please see Option #6 of* [This](https://opensource.com/article/17/5/7-cool-kde-tweaks-will-improve-your-life) *Site*.

[image]

**Select Icons**....

[image]

**I use the Whiteglass Icons**

[image]

Comment: Will this work with KDE (Kubuntu)?

Comment: yes there is i have to reinstall again there was some missing files can not launch the apps it did not appears on my system & settings..thanks i will info after im done installing

Comment: com.canonical.notify-osd...in order to work properly unity tweak tool recommends you install the necessary packages..

Comment: I can not install unity tweak tool

Comment: The following schema is missing... com.canonical.notify-osd..... already complete remove ang install again but with no success..is there other ways?

Comment: It works fine now i try the option #6... i go to system settings and choose icons themes with different style and hit apply and Restart..